# CakePHP DebugKit equivalent on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If there any gem that offer a "debug" toolbar on browser, not to pause execution, just to have an overview of what happen on the request, CakePHP have a really nice plugin called DebugKit for this, it displays something like:

[image: DebugKit toolbar]

You can see variables that are scoped to the view, the time that it took to process each part of the applicatoin, a sql log, information about the session and the requests.

Sometimes something like that would be very useful, but I'm not able to find something like that for rails, any gem you are aware of?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debugkit for ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092647/debugkit-for-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: [rails_panel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel)

A Chrome extension; you need also to include a gem: meta_request. But it's a nice tool.